# How can I automatically spin up my ec2 instance, run a command and then shut it down?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to run a machine learning model on my data in redshift postgres database once a week.

I set up my R script as a rest api using `plumbr` and then I set it up to be managed as a task by `pm2`. I have it so the task starts up when the `ec2` instance starts up and then keeps running.

All I need to do to get the R script to run and upload new data from the machine learning model is to run a simple curl request `curl http://localhost:4208/main`

The whole process for the model takes about 10 minutes.

How can I automate make the process of starting the ec2 instance, running the curl request and then shutting it down? Is this something that can be done with AWS Beanstalk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in launch instructions (user data) when a new EC2 instance is launched. Assuming you're running a Linux AMI:

So something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl http://localhost:4208/main
```

More information can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

That will launch your EC2 instance with the proper curl request to get you started.

Now to automate the launch of an EC2 instance with the launch script you create, you'll need to use the command line.

You can learn more about that here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-ec2-instances.html

Answer (score 2):

Write below script in #User data of your ec2 . this script will execute your program the it will wait for 10 minute and with the help of ec2 instance metadata it will stop your ec2 .

Prerequisites for this is launch ec2 instance with role which has ec2 instance stop access.

Reference url for ec2 instance role creation is [enter link description here][1]

test.sh

```
## Your Program
curl http://localhost:4208/main

# expecting curl call will finish in 10 min.
sleep 10m

# teminating your ec2 instance.
Imageid=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-id`
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids $Imageid
```