# How can I capture the output of an EC2 instance that is spun up, runs a command, and then shuts down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, error-handling

I am using the approach outlined in [How can I automatically spin up my ec2 instance, run a command and then shut it down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55821189/how-can-i-automatically-spin-up-my-ec2-instance-run-a-command-and-then-shut-it) to run a VM on EC2 with #User data. However, I want a reliable way to capture the output of the script even if it has errors in it. Right now the idea is to have the script's output be written to S3. However, something needs to do that. Is there another way?

I got this for free when running under EMR.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-log-user-data/  This logs to the serial console which would be accessible from an api call / in web console, but I don't think it would last long after an instance was terminated.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I want something that lasts.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/EC2NewInstanceCWL.html heres another option, that might be free depending on volume and retention.  Sends to cloudwatch logs which has. 5gb free tier.

Comment: Otherwise if S3 is what you want, and your user data script is bash, you can `trap` `EXIT` to run a command to `aws s3 cp` your instance's log file to S3 when the script ends.  I'm not sure if that would work if the instance terminates itself in the script.  Unfortunately you can't progressively stream data to s3 so you have to write the whole log once you get done logging it.

Comment: one more option: log to console, then write an event hook that triggers when an instance is terminated and can copy the console log to s3.  I think this is what I would try first because then you get the s3 logs and the real time streaming and it should be close to free (s3 is really cheap and lambda has a generous free tier)